# How do I make a JFrame an accurate number of pixels in size?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am trying to draw some specific graphics onto a `JPanel` (which is added onto the `JFrame`) like a grid. I am using the length and width of the frame to size the cells on the grid. When the grid is painted, it doesn't fit into the default frame size and I need to re-size the frame manually to be able to see the entire grid. In my example:

I have a 600x600 frame.
I want to draw a 20x20 grid.
Therefore each frame should be 30x30 pixels across.

I draw the grid and this is what occurs after code completion:

[image]

I tried looking for ways to fix this, but everyone says to use `frame.pack()` which doesn't work in my case because I'm not using (adding) any `JComponent` objects in the panel, it is all custom rendered.

Comment: *"because I'm not using any JComponents"* - Then what are you using?

Comment: The viewable area of any window is the size of the window minus the frame decorations insets...

Comment: The real question here should be *"How do I make a frame **content** an accurate number of pixels in size?"*, then the answer is easy.  Have the component that renders the content return a suitable preferred size (and then pack the frame after adding the component).

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"..what are you using?"* By 'using' I think the OP meant 'adding' (to the `JPanel` being painted).  OP:- please check my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28956101/revisions), which I *think* is what you mean, and more clearly worded.

Comment: @AndrewThompson This still calls into question what the OP is actually doing.  They could be painting directly to the window...some replicate example would make all the difference.  And "using" is a loose term.  What "are you doing" might be better

Comment: @MadProgrammer Note the first sentence of the original post.  *"I am trying to draw some specific graphics onto a JPanel.."*  And yes, there are still lots of questions that are better answered in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). ...And I'm surprised it took me this long to get around to suggesting that the OP post one.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yeah and then they go onto state that they're not using any `JComponent`s...:P

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 2):

> but everyone says to use frame.pack()

Which is correct.

> I'm not using (adding) any JComponent objects in the panel, it is all custom rendered.

If you are not adding components to the panel, then you are doing custom painting on the panel. Therefore you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your custom painting panel to return the size of the panel, so that the pack() method can work properly.

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension(600, 600);
}
```

Now when you pack() frame the frame size will be the size of the panel, plus the size of the decorations (title bar, borders) on the frame no matter what OS or LAF you use for your application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that when designating dimensions for a JFrame, the compiler takes the size of the borders(insets) from the given dimensions. This results in the display portion of the window being slightly smaller than the dimensions specified. The way to get around this is to add the insets' dimensions to your frame dimensions:

```
setSize(600+getInsets().right+getInsets().left,600+getInsets().top+getInsets().bottom);
```

Or if you want to use SetSize(Dimension):

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(600+getInsets().right+getInsets().left,600+getInsets().top+getInsets().bottom);
setSize(d);
```